# SQL query into Hibernate query

Tags: sql, hibernate

How do I write this SQL query as a Hibernate query?

```
 SELECT u.id, u.orderId, p.productName, u.key2, i.forsor_id
 FROM `ub_orders` u JOIN
      productInfo p
      ON p.productId=u.productId JOIN
      ir i
      ON u.key2=i.id
 WHERE p.productName LIKE '%OSS HOSTING FEE%' AND
       u.createdDate > 2014-02-1 AND
       forsor_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY u.key2;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I readily see two problems.  The first is the use of backticks and the second is the need for single quotes around the date constant:

```
 SELECT u.id, u.orderId, p.productName, u.key2, i.forced_matrix_sponsor_id
 FROM ubercart_reseller_orders u join
      productInfo p
      on p.productId=u.productId join
      ir i
      on u.key2=i.id
 where p.productName like '%OSS HOSTING FEE%' and
       u.createdDate > '2014-02-1' and
 ----------------------^
       forced_matrix_sponsor_id is null
 order by u.key2;
```

Comment: is this hibernate query

Comment: @Sundara . . . Hibernate has a query language called HQL that looks a lot like SQL -- although there are many differences from other databases.  It is well documented (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html).